# Saving ManyToMany data in Django 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to save data in django with ManyToMany fields via django-bootstrap-modal-forms package for modal forms with no success. I tried overriding the save method but `kwargs['instance']` always return an empty dict of the ManyToMany field (`'suppliers'`):

```
{'name': 'product_1', 'all_suppliers': <QuerySet []>, 'suppliers': <QuerySet []>}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is updating the `suppliers` for a `product` and/or updating `products` from a `supplier`

Totally new to Django so please excuse the bad programming style

Could you please help me.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    supplier_products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
# views.py
class ProductUpdateView(BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product/product_update.html'
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list_view')


class SupplierUpdateView(BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Supplier
    template_name = 'product/supplier_update.html'
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('supplier_list_view')
```

**forms.py**

```
# forms.py
class ProductForm(BSModalForm):
    all_suppliers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Supplier.objects.all(),required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            suppliers = kwargs['instance'].supplier_set.all()
            print(type(kwargs['instance']))
            self.fields['suppliers'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=suppliers)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'notes']
        fields.append('all_suppliers')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your mistake is because you need to save the product instance before adding manytomanyfield (suppliers) to It. Look at this [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). I hope to help you! =)

I believe it stays something like this (take this as a base to your search):

```py
def save(self, commit=True):
        product = super(ProductForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            product.save()
            suppliers = self.cleaned_data['supplier_products']
            for s in suppliers:
               product.suppliers.add(s)
            product.save()

        return product
```

Comment: That's what I thought I should do but as I mentioned, the output gives me an empty QuerySet:
`{'name': 'product_1', 'all_suppliers': <QuerySet []>, 'suppliers': <QuerySet []>}`

Comment: I was having the same problem a while ago. And what I did was something like what I showed you. Try to go back to the **save** method and make your adjustments. I believe it can work.

Comment: Just to lift any confusion or doubt, I dropped django bootstrap modal form and rebased my view and form on CreateView and ModelForm but still having the same issue, I checked the cleaned data and it shows empty QuerySet for the extra field. I believe the problem is something else, didn't figured it out yet... But I'll keep digging... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this and I'm using the admin screens, which you'd think would handle this situation of adding a new Tag to a new Tool.

[ManyToManyField breaking in Admin screens and shouldn't be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625639/manytomanyfield-breaking-in-admin-screens-and-shouldnt-be)